# Rails api PUSH chat message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, push-notification, chat, json-api

I am developing a Rails application that will be exposed by API only. The application has a real time chat system which involves users submitting data to the server (via API calls), but what I want to push this data to other clients.

what is the best way to send data/message to other client?

Comment: parse.com, pusher.com and many more. Or provide more details for your problem to find the most appropriate solution

Answer (score 0):

Even knowing that your question will be closed, because at least you need to put some code (what you have now) I recently came across a blog post that will guide you in the right direction.

What you need is the new Rails 5 (still in beta) and the new component called ActionCable. [Here you have the blog post](https://medium.com/when-code-explodes/stream-comments-with-rails-5-and-actioncable-49176b8797c8#.f8axva6qw) describing how to use it. Also you have the [DHH ActionCable examples](https://github.com/rails/actioncable-examples).

Under the wood it uses [websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) for full-duplex communications, ensuring your users will get the notifications.

Since you want an API based solution, you may need more work to get it with your frontend framework.